# SpringMVC won't map hierarchical urls

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem with my rest endpoint mappings.  They involve a hierarchical natural key.  So I want paths where I shorten the path, and it will then get results from a larger item space.

The issue is, the most fully qualified path works and the leas qualified path works, but not the two paths in the middle; they return 404 without ever getting into the controller.  So I assume it is an mapping issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookmark/v1")
public class BookmarkRestController
{
  // this works
  @GetMapping("/member/{memberId}/content/{contentSource}/{contentType}/{contentId}")
  public ResponseEntity<Bookmark> read(
    @PathVariable final String memberId,
      @PathVariable final String contentSource,
      @PathVariable final String contentType,
      @PathVariable final String contentId)
  {
    ...
  }

  // this returns 404 without ever getting into the controller
  @GetMapping("/member/{memberId}content/{contentSource}/{contentType}")
  public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(
    @PathVariable final String memberId,
    @PathVariable final String contentSource,
    @PathVariable final String contentType)
  {
    ...
  }

  // this returns 404 without ever getting into the controller
  @GetMapping("/member/{memberId}content/{contentSource}")
  public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(
    @PathVariable final String memberId,
    @PathVariable final String contentSource)
  {
    ...
  }

  // this works
  @GetMapping("/member/{memberId}")
  public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(@PathVariable final String memberId)
  {
    ...
  }

}

@GetMapping("/member/{memberId}/content/{contentSource}/{contentType}/{contentId}")
public ResponseEntity<Bookmark> read(
  @PathVariable final String memberId,
    @PathVariable final String contentSource,
    @PathVariable final String contentType,
    @PathVariable final String contentId)

@GetMapping("/member/{memberId}content/{contentSource}/{contentType}")
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(
    @PathVariable final String memberId,
    @PathVariable final String contentSource,
    @PathVariable final String contentType)

@GetMapping("/member/{memberId}content/{contentSource}")
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(
    @PathVariable final String memberId,
    @PathVariable final String contentSource)

@GetMapping("/member/{memberId}")
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Bookmark>> read(@PathVariable final String memberId)
```

Comment: Is it intentional, that you didn't put a `/` in `{memberId}content`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url mapping is incorrect for those two methods, i.e., you are missing `/` in between, so you need to change this `/member/{memberId}content` to `/member/{memberId}/content`

`/member/{memberId}content` url (with out `/`) works only when the request is like `/member/1content`. 
In other words, when the controller is mapped to `/member/{memberId}content` url & the request comes as `/member/1/content` 9with path separator) you will get 404 error.

Comment: Wow.   Thank you for the fresh set of eyes. I looked at that code 100 times.